# Control over std::vector reallocation

Tags: c++, stl, insert, stdvector

By reading the `std::vector` reference I understood that

1. calling `insert` when the the maximum capacity is reached will cause the reallocation of the `std::vector` (causing iterator invalidation) because new memory is allocated for it with a bigger capacity. The goal is to keep the guarantee about contiguous data.
2. As long as I stick below the maximum capacity `insert` will not cause that (and iterators will be intact).

My question is the following:

When `reserve` is called automatically by `insert`, is there any way to control how much new memory must be reserved?

Suppose that I have a vector with an initial capacity of 100 and, when the maximum capacity is hit, I want to allocate an extra 20 bytes.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always track it yourself and call reserve before it would allocate, e.g.

```
static const int N = 20 // Amount to grow by
if (vec.capacity() == vec.size()) {
  vec.reserve(vec.size() + N);
}
vec.insert(...);
```

You can wrap this in a function of your own and call that function instead of calling `insert()` directly.

Comment: I don't see how this is sensible. The call to `reserve()` will reallocate all the elements, and then you get another set of copies when you call `insert()`. Besides that, `reserve()` is only guaranteed to reserve *at least* the requested size and may in fact reserve more.

Comment: The question was how can I control it. This is the most control you can get and even if it does allocate more you never get allocations that aren't caught by this if statement even though they can be bigger than you asked.

Comment: In that case I agree - what you win from this doesn't seem worth the hassle. Ill edit when I'm not on mobile.